# Best way to stop SQL SELECT Statement once a value is found in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

The below query returns 3 rows:

```
  SELECT ffv.flex_value
    FROM fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs, fnd_flex_values ffv, fnd_flex_values_tl ffvtl
   WHERE     ffvs.flex_value_set_name = 'XXXXXXXX'
         AND ffv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
         AND ffv.flex_value_id = ffvtl.flex_value_id
         AND ffv.enabled_flag = 'Y'
         AND ffv.summary_flag <> 'Y'
         AND ffvtl.language = USERENV ('LANG')
```

As soon as I add the below EXISTS Clause, it takes forever to return the same 3 rows or 1 or 2 rows. I cannot modify this function or create a copy of it since its a cloud and we don't have any option to create/modify the functions.
The below table inside the exists clause has roughly around 159330 rows

```
AND EXISTS
                 (SELECT 1
                    FROM gl_code_combinations gcc
                   WHERE     gcc.segment1 = ffv.flex_value
                         AND fnd_flex_xml_publisher_apis.process_kff_combination_1 (
                                 'FLEX_SECURE',
                                 'GL',
                                 'GL#',
                                 gcc.chart_of_accounts_id,
                                 NULL,
                                 gcc.code_combination_id,
                                 'ALL',
                                 'Y',
                                 'SECURITY') = 'Y')
```

Is there any best possible way to increase the performance of this query in Oracle SQL?

Comment: _I cannot modify this function_. Do you mean you can't modify `fnd_flex_xml_publisher_apis.process_kff_combination_1` but you can modify the SELECT query that calls that function? Or are you saying you cannot modify any of the code shown?

Comment: It is the function call to "fnd_flex_xml_publisher_apis.process_kff_combination_1" in the WHERE clause that is causing your pain. It must be spun up and executed separately for every row in your query - in other words you have your top-level query plus at least 159330 separate sub-queries for each row in "gl_code_combinations", each of which must return 1-3 rows. In general you do not want complex functions or sub-queries in your WHERE clause for exactly that reason.

Comment: Try the hint `no_query_transformation` to the top-level `select`. With some luck that should suffice to prevent the Optimizer from rewriting the query in a way it thinks is good, but you know is bad. Another thought though: do you know for sure that the evaluation of the function doesn't take forever, even on 2-3 inputs?

Comment: I have tried the function for 3 rows and it returns the value within a second. I need the EXIST clause to come out of it once it finds the function value = Y for any 1 row out of 150k rows. and the function should not be called for all the 150k rows.

Comment: Also the hint "no_query_transformation" did not work. @Shannon: the first case. I cannot modify the function but I can modify the SELECT statement

Answer (score 2):

As @pmdba points out above, functions in the WHERE clause are a big problem for performance. The EXISTS condition is evaluated for every row in the combined dataset, so the cloud function can be called hundreds of thousands of times.

If you want your function to only be called on the resultset of the main query (3 rows), there's a couple techniques you can try.

The first is to move your main query into an inline view, and put the WHERE condition with the function outside of it. This doesn't always work for me - sometimes the optimizer will rewrite these queries to remove the inline view - but it often helps.

```
select flex_value
from (
    SELECT ffv.flex_value
        FROM fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs, fnd_flex_values ffv, fnd_flex_values_tl ffvtl
       WHERE     ffvs.flex_value_set_name = 'XXXXXXXX'
             AND ffv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
             AND ffv.flex_value_id = ffvtl.flex_value_id
             AND ffv.enabled_flag = 'Y'
             AND ffv.summary_flag <> 'Y'
             AND ffvtl.language = USERENV ('LANG')
    ) ffv
where EXISTS (SELECT 1 from g1_code_combinations gcc ... )
```

A second way is to move your function into a SELECT clause. The SELECT clause is the last part of the query which is evaluated, so a function there will only be called once for each row that's returned. In this case, a maximum of 3 times.

```
select flex_value
from (
    SELECT ffv.flex_value,
            fnd_flex_xml_publisher_apis.process_kff_combination_1 (
                             'FLEX_SECURE',
                             'GL',
                             'GL#',
                             gcc.chart_of_accounts_id,
                             NULL,
                             gcc.code_combination_id,
                             'ALL',
                             'Y',
                             'SECURITY') func_result
        FROM fnd_flex_value_sets ffvs
        JOIN fnd_flex_values ffv
            ON ffv.flex_value_set_id = ffvs.flex_value_set_id
        JOIN fnd_flex_values_tl ffvtl
            ON ffv.flex_value_id = ffvtl.flex_value_id
        JOIN gl_code_combinations gcc
            ON gcc.segment1 = ffv.flex_value
       WHERE     ffvs.flex_value_set_name = 'XXXXXXXX'
             AND ffv.enabled_flag = 'Y'
             AND ffv.summary_flag <> 'Y'
             AND ffvtl.language = USERENV ('LANG')
    ) v
where func_result = 'Y'
```

Comment: Hello kfinity,I tried both the queries. both are still taking a lot of time to execute. The function is the culprit for 150k rows but I want the function to be called only thrice for the 3 rows. Both the queries are trying for 150k rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ROWNUM` predicate to an inline view to stop optimizer transformations and force the function to run at the end, after all the filtering of the inline view is complete.

```
SELECT ...
(
    ...
    --Prevent optimizer transformations so that the function will run *after* all filtering.
    AND ROWNUM >= 1
)
WHERE fnd_flex_xml_publisher_apis.process_kff_combination_1(...) = 'Y';
```

Simply re-writing the query into a different order will almost never change the execution plan. Adding `ROWNUM` makes Oracle think that this is a Top-N reporting query, where the order matters, and that will prevent all predicate pushing, view merging, and other transformations. A more official way to accomplish this is with optimizer hints, but getting those hints right is difficult.

Comment: This did not work. Still facing the performance issue.

Comment: @VinayG Can you post the full version of the query with the ROWNUM condition? That trick should have worked - I've used it dozens of times. Or maybe you should double-check running the function with the three sets of literals and make sure the function isn't running slow for one particular set of parameters.